# How to get a number, but not a list, of the dimension of your array?

Tags: list-manipulation

I need to use the dimension of a certain array, to use it as a bounder in a loop afterwards. The problem is that I get a list, when write :

```
Dimensions[ai]= {2}

aiod = Table[ai[[i]] - 1, {i, 1, Dimensions[ai], 1}]
```

and it does not work. I need to get "2" instead of {2}.

Comment: You can use `Part`, as in `{2}[[1]]`.

Comment: Or `Length`, if the first (outermost) dimension is what you want.

Comment: What is your first line `Dimensions[ai]={2}` intended to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the first (outermost) dimension is what you want, use `Length`:

```
aiod = Table[ai[[i]]-1, {i, Length[ai]}]
```

Notice I've used a simpler iterator specification.

Anyway, if this is your real problem, then be aware that arithmetic operations in Mathematica are `Listable`, so you can just write

```
ai - 1
```

Comment: This might be useful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7922/8